# How to solve PHP undefinedindex error in wordpress widget?

Tags: php, widget

During building widget, I am facing some PHP error problem.The following code shows  error:
All codes are below:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Strawberry Popular Post Widgets
 * Plugin URI: http://arifhossin.com/
 * Description: A widget that shows popular posts ( Specified by comment post view ).
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Arif Hossin
 * Author URI: http://www.arifhossin.com
 *
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'personalblog_popular_posts_widget' );
    function personalblog_popular_posts_widget() {
        register_widget( 'Personalblog_Popular_Posts' );
    }

    class Personalblog_Popular_Posts extends WP_Widget{
        // Initialize the widget
        public function __construct() {
            parent::WP_Widget(
                'personalblog_popular_posts_widget', esc_html__('Strawberry: Popular Posts Widget','strawberry'), array('description' => esc_html__('Strawberry:A widget that shows Polupar Posts', 'strawberry')));  
        }

        // Output of the widget
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            extract($args);
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
            $posts_order_by = $instance['posts_order_by'];
            $poular_posts_time_range = $instance['poular_posts_time_range'];
            $num_fetch = $instance['num_fetch'];

            // Opening of widget
            echo $args['before_widget'];

            // Open of title tag
            if( !empty($title) ){ 
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; 
            }
            $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'post',
            'posts_per_page'        => $num_fetch,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
            'no_found_rows'         => true,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'orderby'               => $posts_order_by,
            'order'                 => 'DESC',
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'after'  => $posts_time_range,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $posts_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <?php if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <div class="pb-recent-posts-widget-section clearfix">
                <ul class="pb-recent-post-widget-list">
                    <?php while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('widget-post-entry clearfix'); ?>>
                                <figure class="pb-recent-post-widget-thumbnail-section">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'widget-post-image' ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </figure>

                            <div class="pb-recent-post-widget-section">
                                <h2 class="pb-recent-post-widget-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <?php if( pb_theme_options('enable_widget_meta') == '1' ) { ?>
                                    <div class="pb-recent-post-widget-meta clearfix">
                                        <ul>
                                        <?php if( pb_theme_options('widget_meta_date') == '1' ) { ?>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span></li>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php if( pb_theme_options('widget_meta_comments') == '1' ) { ?>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-comments">
                                                <span>
                                                <?php printf( _nx( '', '%1$s', 'comments title', get_comments_number(), 'personalblog' ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) ); ?>
                                                </span>
                                              </i>
                                           </li>
                                           <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul>
                                        <?php if( pb_theme_options('widget_meta_category') == '1' ) { ?>
                                            <li><p class="category"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"> </i> <?php the_category(', '); ?></p></li>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        <?php if( pb_theme_options('widget_meta_likes') == '1' ) { ?>
                                           <li><?php echo getPostLikeLink( get_the_ID() )?> </li>
                                           <?php } ?>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        // Closing of widget

        echo $after_widget;
        }

        // Widget Form
        public function form( $instance ) {

        $title = isset($instance['title'])? $instance['title']: 'Popular Posts';
        $posts_order_by = isset($instance['posts_order_by'])? $instance['posts_order_by']: '';
        $poular_posts_time_range = isset($instance['poular_posts_time_range'])? $instance['poular_posts_time_range']: '';
        $num_fetch = isset($instance['num_fetch'])? $instance['num_fetch']: 5;


            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Title :', 'strawberry'); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr ( $this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('posts_order_by')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order by:', 'strawberry' ); ?></label>
                <select name="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_name('posts_order_by')); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('posts_order_by')); ?>" class="widefat">
                    <option value="meta_value_num"<?php selected( $instance['posts_order_by'], 'post_views_count' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'View Count', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="comment_count"<?php selected( $instance['posts_order_by'], 'comment_count' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'Most commented', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                </select>
           </p>

            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('poular_posts_time_range')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Time Range:', 'strawberry' ); ?></label>
                <select name="<?php echo esc_attr ( $this->get_field_name('poular_posts_time_range')); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr ( $this->get_field_id('poular_posts_time_range')); ?>" class="widefat">
                    <option value="0"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '0' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'All time', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="1 year ago"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '1 year ago' ); ?>><?php _e( 'This year', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="1 month ago"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '1 month ago' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'This month', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="1 week ago"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '1 week ago' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'This week', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                    <option value="1 day ago"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '1 day ago' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'Past 24 hours', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('num_fetch')); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Num Fetch :', 'strawberry'); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_id('num_fetch')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr ($this->get_field_name('num_fetch')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $num_fetch; ?>" />
            </p>


            <?php
        }

        // Update the widget
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['posts_order_by'] = $new_instance['posts_order_by'];
        $instance['poular_posts_time_range'] =$new_instance['poular_posts_time_range'];
        $instance['num_fetch'] = $new_instance['num_fetch'];
        return $instance;
    }



    }
    ?>
```

**Error:**
1)Undefined index: posts_order_by-126 line

```
<option value="meta_value_num"<?php selected( $instance['posts_order_by'], 'post_views_count' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'View Count', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
```

2)Undefined index: posts_order_by-127 line

```
<option value="comment_count"<?php selected( $instance['posts_order_by'], 'comment_count' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'Most commented', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
```

3)Undefined index: poular_posts_time_range-134 line

```
<option value="0"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '0' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'All time', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
```

4)Undefined index: poular_posts_time_range-135 line

```
<option value="1 year ago"<?php selected( $instance['poular_posts_time_range'], '1 year ago' ); ?>><?php esc_html_e( 'This year', 'strawberry' ); ?></option>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All codes perhaps but not the value of `$instance`.  `public function form( $instance )` where is that called from and what is the value of that variable, because it doesn't contain your index, obviously.  PHP rarely lies about errors...

Comment: Please see edited version, and let me know how to solve.Thanks

Comment: Just FYI you do know what this does?  `extract($args);`  Your use of it suggests that you don't; http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php  -- for example after using extract, this `$args['before_widget']` is simply `$before_widget`

Comment: Can you just put the value of `$instance` in there? I don't feel like deciphering all that.  `print_r( $instance )` just inside that function...  I am sure you will see the index is not there.  As to where it is, ... well that I cannot say.

Comment: Undefined index means the key you're using doesn't exist in that array. Check your inputs or put in some default values. The errors are there to stop people mistyping variables or to ensure you're using the the right one. If you expect that some keys/variables may not be set and `null` is an acceptable value, you can simply put an `@` immediately before that variable. However, it's better to explictly set defaults to make your code more readable.